# Swift Compiler Eror: No such module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

I have an old Swift app that was building fine on XCode 10.3 (OS: 10.15.7), but after upgrading to latest MacOS (12.4) and XCode 13.4 I get "No such module: 'ObjectMapper'" when trying to build.

I am using Carthage for dependency management and Carthage update appears to work, e.g:

`carthage update --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS`.

Here is the line in Cartfile for ObjectMapper:
`github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 4.2`

Here is the "Link Binary With Libaries" section in Build Phases:
[image: Link Binary With Libaries]

In the Run Script section: `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`

It has been a while since I last did XCode or Swift development, so I am probably missing something obvious.

Help solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: ObjectMapper hasn’t been updated for 2 years, so maybe it is no longer compatible.

Comment: Well I would be happy with such a message. You don't need that framework since Swift 4. Take a look at Codable protocol.

Comment: @LeoDabus I would be happy to rewrite the application to remove that library if that was all it was, but there are several other libraries that are still needed, which get the same error (once you remove ObjectMapper, the next library gives "No such Module").  Perhaps you can help solve the "Module not Found" issue instead?